# How Can I Set Width Of A Razor Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I Want To Set The Width Of Razor Grid In MVC 3 ....Please Any One Guide Me . I will Be Very Thankful If Any Also Tell Me The Way To Make Grid More Attractive And Beautiful

Answer (score 1):

[CSS](http://www.csstutorial.net/) is a good way to achieve this. And here's a [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrebaltieri/archive/2010/11/02/asp-net-mvc-3-working-with-webgrid-part-2.aspx) which illustrates different techniques for applying class names to different parts of the WebGrid.